# Danganronpa V3 Video/audio desync (spoiler free)

Tags: technical-issues, danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony

After buying Danganronpa V3 on release date a couple days ago, I've been having a great time and the game itself runs perfectly fine. The problem I'm having is that when an animated cutscene occurs, such as Monokuma's reveal, it is severely slowed down, yet the sound progresses at normal speed. Now I don't have any sort of gaming setup, but my computer is good enough to run the regular parts of the game at normal speed. I want to sort this out ideally before the first trial, so any executions aren't spoilt by something like a desync in sound. Thanks in advance.

Note: this problem did not occur in Danganronpa 1 or 2, though I guess my computer has got older since then.

Edit: Here is my laptop's specs - I have a quad core CPU with 6GB of RAM and a 1.50GHz clock speed. 50GB remaining on the hard disk. It is about 6 years old so it is getting on a bit.

Comment: Can you post your specs for your PC? It would be helpful to see if it is your computer that is the problem.

Comment: Sure. I have a quad core CPU with 6GB of RAM and a 1.50GHz clock speed. 50GB remaining on the hard disk. It is about 6 years old so it is getting on a bit. It's no gaming laptop by any stretch, but it manages with most non-AAA games.

Comment: 1.5GHz cpu and no video card is probably getting a bit weak for modern not-heavily-optimised games. Are you running it in fullscreen? If not, try it, or if so, try at a smaller resolution.

Comment: While I cannot answer for certain I do believe this is an issue with the computer. Danganronpa V3 requires at least an i3-4170 @ 3.70GHz and a GTX 460 minimum.

Comment: I see. I knew a new PC would be due soon anyway. Thanks to both for the help either way. I'm gonna have to make due with a lower resolution for now, and start putting a budget together.